# In ES6 synthax, how can I do named export using variable key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, requirejs

I have an `Object` I dont know the whole content.

I want to produce a named export of everything, as a reminder, this is a named export :

```
 export const myFunction = () => {};
```

How can I iterate on the keys of my object, and export everything as named ?

Something like this does not work because I am trying to initialize `module.exports`:

```
const cfgEnv = require(`./${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}`);

Object.keys(cfgEnv).forEach((key) => {
  if (!module.exports) {
    module.exports = {};
  }
  module.exports[key] = cfgEnv[key];
});
```

Comment: Why cant you just module.exports = cfgEnv; its going to be the same thing no?

Comment: "*Something like this does not work*" - why, what is the error you are getting? How are you trying to use that module, and what environment-dependant module are you requiring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
const cfgEnv = require(`./${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}`);
module.exports = cfgEnv;
```

it will work like

```
module.exports = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to produce a named export using variable key?

You cannot. ES6 module exports must be static.

> I am trying to initialize `module.exports`

That's not ES6 module syntax, that's a CommonJs module. But doing so is relatively trivial using `Object.assign`:

```
module.exports = Object.assign({}, require(`./${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}`));
```